# invalid value for 'manifest_version'...Must be an integer greater tha zero

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load my first chrome app using the experimental extensions API, however when I do so I receive the following error message:

*invalid value for manifest version, must be an integer greater than zero*

Here is a rendition of my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "name": "Timemaps European Exploration",
    "description": "My first Timemaps Chrome App.",
    "version": "2",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "app":{
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
    "icons": 
    { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
     }
```

I have explicitly stated in my manifest that the manifest version is an integer greater than zero. Why am I receiving this error message???

Comment: Could you remove the last comma and try again?

Comment: done! last comma removed. just tried to reload in chrome...still receive the same error :(

Comment: Are you sure you've copy and pasted correctly?  I can load this fine, but if I change it to: `"manifest_version": "2",`, then I get the error message you mention.

Comment: I have run the chrome app again in my browser but am still receiving the same error message. I made sure I also copied and pasted the code correctly as advised.

Comment: It works for me, too. Are you sure you're not accidentally including an invisible character or somehow typing a weird character that looks like a 2?

Comment: No! the number 2 is quite apparent and it certainly does not work when i run it on chrome. I would send a print screen but apparently I do not have enough reputations????? :( not good

Comment: I know that my code is correct...but I cannot work out why it does not run